# Collision detection with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a pretty simple world I've created with three.js. I'm making a really basic plat-former and I'm trying to get collision detection to work when a user runs on top of a coin to update a text counter of how many coins have been touched.  As of right now nothing occurs when i run over the coins, no JavaScript console errors either.  Any help would be amazing.

I've been trying to use a raycaster to detect the collision.  Here's some snippets of what I have, I can dump more or all 600ish lines of code if requested.'

```
<div id="info">
    <h1 style="color: white">0/10</h1>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var coin = [];
var raycaster;
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
... //Lots more variables I've left out for readability


initThree();
initCannon();
animate();

function initThree() {

            clock = new THREE.Clock();

            //Renderer
            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true} );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( width, height );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xb2b2b2 );
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x9bacc6, 0, 7000 );

            //Camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, width/height, 1, 10000 );
            //camera.position.set( 3000, 3000, 3000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 10, 0 );
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            //Controls      
            controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls( camera );

            var blocker = document.getElementById( 'blocker' );
            var instructions = document.getElementById( 'instructions' );

            //Lock control when focused
            instructions.addEventListener( 'click', function () {

                controls.lock();

            }, false );

            //Hide overlay
            controls.addEventListener( 'lock', function () {

                instructions.style.display = 'none';
                blocker.style.display = 'none';

            } );

            controls.addEventListener( 'unlock', function () {

                blocker.style.display = 'block';
                instructions.style.display = '';

            } );
            scene.add( controls.getObject() );

            //Raycaster
            raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3( 0, -1, 0 ), 0, 10 );   

            loadTrees();
            loadCoins();
            createLight();
            createGround();
            createWater();
            createSky();
        }

function loadCoins() {      

            var coinPath = '../models/gltf/coin/scene.gltf';
            loader.load( coinPath, function( gltf ) {
                coin[0] = gltf.scene;
                coin[0].position.set(3300,1500,1000);
                coin[0].scale.set(100,100,100);
                scene.add( coin[0] );
            });
            loader.load( coinPath, function( gltf ) {
                coin[1] = gltf.scene;
                coin[1].position.set(3300,1500,-1000);
                coin[1].scale.set(100,100,100);
                scene.add( coin[1] );
             ...
            });

    function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            update();
            render();
        }

function update() {
            //controls.update();

            world.step( timeStep );

            ground.position.copy( groundBody.position );
            ground.quaternion.copy( groundBody.quaternion );

            var mixDelta = clock.getDelta();
            if( mixer != null) {
                mixer.update( mixDelta );
                mixer2.update( mixDelta );
                mixer3.update( mixDelta );
            }

            raycaster.ray.origin.copy( controls.getObject().position );
            raycaster.ray.origin.y -= 100;

            //checks to see if intersecting object array
            var intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects( coin );

            var touching = intersections.length > 0;

            var time = performance.now();
            var delta = ( time - prevTime ) / 1000;

            velocity.x -= velocity.x * 10 * delta;
            velocity.z -= velocity.z * 10 * delta;
            velocity.y -= 9.8 * 100 * delta; //100 = mass //9.8

            direction.z = Number( moveForward ) - Number( moveBackward );
            direction.x = Number( moveLeft ) - Number( moveRight );
            direction.normalize(); //consistent movement in all directions

            if( moveForward || moveBackward ) {
                velocity.z -= direction.z * 7500 * delta;
            }
            if( moveLeft || moveRight ) {
                velocity.x -= direction.x * 7500 * delta;
            }

            //Stops when runs into an object
            if ( touching === true ) {
                    coinCount += 1;
                    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = coinCount + "/10";
            }


            controls.getObject().translateX( velocity.x * delta );
            controls.getObject().translateY( velocity.y * delta );
            controls.getObject().translateZ( velocity.z * delta );

            //Keep Player within bounds of game
            if ( controls.getObject().position.y < 200 ) {

                    velocity.y = 0;
                    controls.getObject().position.y = 200;

                    canJump = true;

            }               
            if ( controls.getObject().position.x < -4000 ) {
                velocity.x = 0;
                controls.getObject().position.x = -4000;
            }
            if ( controls.getObject().position.x > 4000 ) {
                velocity.x = 0;
                controls.getObject().position.x = 4000;
            }               
            if ( controls.getObject().position.z < -4000 ) {
                velocity.x = 0;
                controls.getObject().position.z = -4000;
            }
            if ( controls.getObject().position.z > 4000 ) {
                velocity.x = 0;
                controls.getObject().position.z = 4000;
            }

            prevTime = time;

            //Update Water
            water.material.uniforms[ "time" ].value += 1.0 / 60.0;

            //Spin Coins
            for( i=0; i<coin.length; i++ ) {
                coin[i].rotation.y += .05;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raycasting is not an ideal collision detection approach for this use case. Consider to represent your coins with simple bounding volumes like [THREE.Box3](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3) (an AABB) or [THREE.Sphere](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Sphere) (a bounding sphere). The player itself will be represented with such a bounding volume, too. In your animation loop you then test if the player's bounding volume intersects with certain objects in your game environment like your coins. This is a much more reliable test than working with a single ray since you can better represent 3D objects with a spatial extension.

BTW: If you are not yet familiar with bounding volumes, I highly recommend to study this topic a bit. AABBs and bounding spheres are very important entities in context of collision detection. A good resource for this is *3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development by Fletcher Dunn Ian Parberry, Chapter 9 Geometric Primitives*.